# Vuforia replacing Teapot with 3D model in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opengl-es, vuforia

Can anyone detail how to replace teapot obj with some custom 3D model object?

I tried changing the teapot PNGs with my custom images but that also doesn't help much except changing colour of Teapot.

From the code it seems the texture gets defined with the help of buildings.txt, How to generate that text file?

Most of the references available online are broken:

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot

http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/

Comment: The [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) has [both](https://web.archive.org/web/20140712090448/https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot) of [those](https://web.archive.org/web/20100217023917/http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/).

Comment: Hey thanks for the archive url.